# Should I centre or standardise variables in a linear mixed model analysis?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multilevel-analysis, standardization

My study is looking at skin lesions in pigs. I have 2 partially cross-classified random factors (weaning pen and finishing pen) and several predictor variables. I have centred pig weights by pen because I want to look at how pig weight, in relation to pen mean, affects the prevalence of aggression lesions. Was this the right thing to do or should I have standardised the variables?